# How to improve humidity sensor (Si7021) accuracy?

Tags: arduino, sensor, humidity

I am trying to measure humidity in a textile factory more accurately.

I found [this sensor Si7021](https://www.robotistan.com/si7021-sicaklik-ve-nem-sensor-karti) (circuit was copied from SparkFun this is the link from [SparkFun.](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/13763)) It is measuring very good. I am comparing with a [Testo 625.](https://www.testo.com/tr-TR/testo-625/p/0563-6251) Both results are almost same.

[image]

This IC is no longer in stock, so I found this IC from [Adafruit](https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-si7021-temperature-plus-humidity-sensor/overview) instead of SparkFun.

[image]

Both of them use a Si7021, but the second one is NOT measuring humidity correctly. For example if I measure 46% with [Testo 625](https://www.testo.com/tr-TR/testo-625/p/0563-6251), it measures 40% humidity. In a second test if I increase the humidity I'm measuring 71% with the Testo 625, but the Adafruit sensor shows 59%. On the other hand [my first sensor](https://www.robotistan.com/si7021-sicaklik-ve-nem-sensor-karti) is almost same with the [Testo 625](https://www.testo.com/tr-TR/testo-625/p/0563-6251) for both measurments.

What is wrong? I don't understand. My only solution is to multiply by a number, but I didn't need this with the SparkFun sensor.

Comment: How accurate is the temperature? Sounds out of spec since accuracy should be 3% for humidity, in which case it is damaged.

Comment: @DKNguyen temperature accurate is good. only 1 or 2 degree differences from testo

Comment: Does this sound relevant? Does it read back a serial number and calibration data? https://www.silabs.com/community/sensors/forum.topic.html/si7021_loses_serial-Lkb7

Comment: I am using this library https://github.com/adafruit/Adafruit_Si7021. It can read serail number. Calibration data? I dont know how to get?

Comment: If you can read the serial number its not that.

Comment: @mehmet you have a misconception in your post ... the picture you posted shows a `module` not an IC per se ... the six pin component on the module is an IC

Comment: @mehmet So what was the problem.
How did you improved the accuracy.

Comment: @AmirChaudhary migret to HDC1080 it is better